# Rollup resolve fails when firebaseui imported

Tags: firebase, firebaseui, rollup

Trying to use rollup with firebase ui and ending up with the following etc.

```
(!) Missing exports
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
node_modules/firebaseui/dist/esm.js
auth is not exported by node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js
```

rollup config:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default [
{  
  input: 'Firebase.js',    
  output: {    
    file: 'Firebase.js',
    format: 'es'
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve()
  ]
}
```

Firebase.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'

firebase.initializeApp({...});
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
```

Also tried `import firebaseui from 'firebaseui'` but no luck.

Sans firebaseui, things work fine, e.g. can rollup a version accessing Firestore just fine.